# Error when changing PrimaryKey (constraint) in table

Tags: c#, sql, linq, t-sql, ado.net

Problem when changing PrimaryKey in table.

**Error**: "Could not create IDENTITY attribute on nullable column."

**Details**:

- "update" is an enumerable of class which is derived from DataSourceObject and IClonable
- "table" is a class derived from DataSourceObject

**Code**:

```
foreach (var u in update)
{
   myList.Add(string.Format("alter table [{0}] alter column {1} {2} {3};", table.Name, u.Name, (u.IsPrimary || u.IsAutoIncrement) ? "not null" : "null"));
}
```

I have also tried removing all the PrimaryKeys like this:

```
foreach (var u in update.Where(x => x.IsPrimary))
{    
   myList.Add(string.Format("alter table [{0}] drop constraint {1}", table.Name, u.Name));
}
```

But it says that current item I'm trying to set as PrimaryKey is not a constraint.

Also I have mentioned that if I change the `if` statement this way (vice versa):

`(u.IsPrimary || u.IsAutoIncrement) ? "null" : "not null";`

when I'm trying to change back primary key, it works. I mean, if I change primary key first, then there's an exception, then I change if statement, then change PrimaryKey it does the business.

**Update**: Now I definitely know that I have to find a constraint name which I want to remove, in my case it will be the default one - ID (it can be done with sys schema, but I don't know how to use it), then I have to drop it, and after all I have to generate a new constraint with new name.

Answer (score 0):

Result query:

```
declare @CONSTRAINTNAME varchar(128);
declare @script nvarchar(max);

select top 1 @CONSTRAINTNAME = t1.CONSTRAINT_NAME
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS t1
where CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' and upper(t1.TABLE_NAME) = @tableName;

set @script = N'alter table [' + @tableName + N'] drop constraint [' + @CONSTRAINTNAME + N']';
exec sp_executesql @script

set @script = N'alter table [' + @tableName + N'] add constraint [' + @tableName + '_' + @columnName + N'] primary key (['+ @columnName +'])';
exec sp_executesql @script
```