# The index is dependent on column T-SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I try changing primary key constraint, but get the error saying: "The index is dependent on column". I tried dropping the index but it seems to do nothing. Am I even doing drop the right way? If no, is there any way to get specific index name? Also here's the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38326732/error-when-changing-primarykey-constraint-in-table) to previous question for more details.

```
declare @CONSTRAINTNAME varchar(128);
declare @script nvarchar(max);

select top 1 @CONSTRAINTNAME = t1.CONSTRAINT_NAME
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS t1
where CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' and upper(t1.TABLE_NAME) = @tableName;

set @script = N'alter table [' + @tableName + N'] drop constraint [' + @CONSTRAINTNAME + N']';
exec sp_executesql @script

--drop
set @script = N'alter table [' + @tableName + N'] drop index[' + @oldIndex+ N']';
exec sp_executesql @script

set @script = N'alter table [' + @tableName + N'] add constraint [' + @tableName + '_' + @columnName + N'] primary key (['+ @columnName +'])';
exec sp_executesql @script
```

Comment: Can you show the definition of all the indexes on that table including clustered and non clustered.

Comment: _dynamic sql which seems to be doing nothing_ - print out your dynamic sql and take a look on what there actually is. Also tables may have schema different from dbo, but I guess this is not your case.

Comment: And you omitted `drop column` code. You are getting error `index is dependent on column`, right? Where is the code modifying the column? Your script may actually perform some activity but in result it creates same index and constraint it just dropped. So I suppose it may seem like it did nothing.

Comment: @KamranFarzami I was trying to get those, but I don't know how to exactly. I tried this: 'select name from sys.indexes' but it just shows all the indexes in database.

Comment: @IvanStarostin Can You please explain me why do I have to drop a column? I just need to change the primary key, and set auto increment if user wants so. If I drop a column, it will clear data, am I right?

Comment: How did you get this message: `"The index is dependent on column"`? After what command?

Comment: @IvanStarostin that's the problem! I don't know when I get it. I have a class that does everything in code behind, and just pass one big query as a string. I'll try to separate the query, and will write back asap!

Comment: @IvanStarostin seems like it occurs when I do: `alter table @tableName alter column @columnName int not null`, which I do after dropping index.

Comment: @morrismasonbonham In the past I have found this site to be quite helpful:http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/sql-server-index-t-sql-statements.html

Comment: @morrismasonbonham right now I don't understand what are you asking about. You had an exception, right? Currently you aren't getting that exception when executing script, right?